ever increasing multiclass-classification with infinite possible tags
Is it possible to have an infinite multiclass classification system with infinite labels? I have been banging my head against a problem for a few days now and while my answers work in a small scale, they end up breaking down in the large scale.
my first approach was to take all representative keywords for a class, map them with weights of importance and based on keyword presence, sum the weights accordingly.
                 dog   cat
bark              1     0
meow              0     1                    tags present:  bark, eat dog food, dig
eat dog food      1    0.5      -->          summation: dog = 3, cat = 1
eat cat food      0.5   1                    result: dog
climb tree        0     1
dig               1    0.5

This worked well but this would result in an infinitely growing table as new keywords are added. And I would need a way to automate the weighting without training data as tags are added without context.
my next approach was to use existing LLMs and cosine similarity. I would take various keywords / phrases that are associated with my classification, map it in the model and then perform cosine similarity on groups of keywords to see which align with my classification.
 dog: dog, bark monster, wolf, puppy, digger, omnivore
 cat: cat, meow, kitty, kitten, tree climber, carnivore
 --> Vectorize list --> Map vectors into model

 keyword: pooch, eat veggies, eat meat, love mud
 --> perform cosine similarity
 
 result: dog   similarity score: 0.XX

This worked great for when I had very few categories (cat vs dog) but when I start to increase the classification list, it starts to break down and ends up guessing incorrectly most of the time with widely varying cosine similarity scores.
I am now currently looking into using word vectorizers to translate keywords into adjacent keywords (TFID) to limit the range of inputs but this doesn't fix the classification issue.
